# How can I submit Django forms without losing previously rendered HTML?

Tags: html, django, forms, django-views

I am new to Django framework.

I am trying to create a mini-project where my UI will have 3 html forms.

[image: Simple django app UI]

The intended workflow is that I will submit a text in **Input String** field.

Then I will submit some substrings of the above submitted string and increase the score.

The problem I am having is when I submit the substring my page reloads and it resets the previously rendered html. Hence, I lose my actual string for which I am submitting substrings.

The html code for Forms

```
  <div style="padding: 20px;">
      <h1>Words Starting with consonants</h1>
      <form id="form2" action="consonant_submit/" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="Stuart">Stuart Text:</label>
          <input type="text" id="stuart" name="stuart">
          <br>
          <label for="2">Stuart Score:</label>
          <input type="text" id="score1" name="score1">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit stuart">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div style="padding: 20px;">
      <h1>Words Starting with consonants</h1>
      <form id="form3" action="vowel_submit/" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="kevin">Kevin Text:</label>
          <input type="text" id="kevin" name="kevin">
          <br>
          <label for="2">Kevin Score:</label>
          <input type="text" id="score2" name="score2">
          <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit kevin">
      </form>
    </div>
```

The consonant_submit & are django view functions.

I am attaching my sample urls.py and sample views.py

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index,name="index"),
    path('consonant_submit/', views.consonant_submit, name='consonant_submit'),
    path('vowel_submit/', views.vowel_submit, name='vowel_submit'),
]
```

And views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    res = render(request,'minion_game.html')
    return res

def consonant_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        input1 = request.POST.get('stuart')
        # Process the stuart data as needed

        res = render(request,'minion_game.html')
        return res
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid request method')

def vowel_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        input2 = request.POST.get('kevin')
        # Process the kevin data as needed
        res = render(request,'minion_game.html')
        return res
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid request method')
```

The problem I am having when I submit substring forms by click Submit Stuart, I am directed to URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/someapp/consonant_submit and I lose the html data that was present in
http://127.0.0.1:8000/someapp .

Is there a way to call django view function on form without calling someapp/consonant_submit and doing the work of consonant_submit view function without tringgering reload of the webpage ?

Comment: If you're looking to send data to the server without reloading the page then the technology you're looking for is called "AJAX".  You can make requests to the server and read the responses in JavaScript code, rather than posting a form.  Your favorite search engine can help you find tutorials and examples to get started with AJAX in a Django application.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about AJAX, I wanted to know if there is any other way. I will learn about AJAX.

Comment: Just look at htmx. It has very simple integration with django. You only need to know some html.